# Is there a way to put a kanban element to the bottom in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

At the moment i am working on an odoo project and i have a kanban view. My question is how do i put a kanban element to the bottom via xml or python. Is there an index for the elements or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean with kanban element? A XML tag or a model record (like a partner for example)?

Comment: Example code (kanban view xml) would be nice here, and ofcourse forvas' question.

Comment: nevermind i already solved it myself, but still thank you for helping me on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I just added `_order = 'finished asc'` to the class. `finished` is a record of type Boolean and tells me if the Task is finished or not.